# Get LinqPad to display same sql as SQL Server Profiler when using Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, linqpad, sql-server-profiler

How can I get LinqPad to display the same generated SQL as SQL Server Profiler?

More specifically, I'd like to have LinqPad SQL format to include 'sp_executesql' when appropriate (see example code below).

I have LinqPad correctly using my .NET DataAccessLayer project dll.

- Meaning I've set the connection to use my `ObjectContext` and selected my EntityDataModel
- So I can call a C# static method via LinqPad like `MyDalClass.GetUser(1)`, which internally uses EF 4.4

When I look at LinqPad's SQL tab, it's displaying the SQL as:

```
-- Region Parameters
DECLARE @p__linq__0 Int = 1
-- EndRegion
SELECT TOP (1) 
[Extent1].[UserId] AS [InviteID], 
[Extent1].[UserName] AS [UserName]
FROM [dbo].[Users] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[UserId] = @p__linq__0
```

But when I view SQL Server Profiler, it's displayed as:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT TOP (1) 
[Extent1].[UserId] AS [InviteID], 
[Extent1].[UserName] AS [UserName]
FROM [dbo].[Users] AS [Extent1]
WHERE [Extent1].[UserId] = @p__linq__0',N'@p__linq__0 int',@p__linq__0=1
```

I'd like to get it so LinqPad SQL shows the same way SQL Server Profiler does
(I've searched on the web but couldn't find an answer).

Thanks for any help or ideas!

Comment: It seems that the conversion to `sp_executesql` is done internally by .NET's `SQLCommand`, and thus it might not be possible to get the actual SQL query executed. Some related articles: [1](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/sqlcommand-calls-sp_executesql-implicitly.3733388/) [2](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bindeshv/2010/07/12/ef-query-execution-pattern-usage-of-sp_executesql-vs-direct-execution-of-sql-statement/) [3](https://berniecook.wordpress.com/2012/11/01/reviewing-the-t-sql-generated-by-linq-to-sql-within-sql-server-profiler/) [4](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/5761/83550)

Comment: Thanks for the information Keith! The links you provided confirm that SQLCommand is indeed altering the EF generated SQL (I had a feeling something might be altering the EF SQL... but I was thinking perhaps SQL Server Profiler was optimizing/normalizing it and displaying this result).  Thanks again for clearing things up :-)